# How to split an ItemCollection into 2 at a specified index?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, itemcollection

This seems like a very basic thing to do, but I can't find any methods to do this. I've checked Intellisense and searched Google with no luck.

I have an `ItemCollection` with ~30 items in it. I'm trying to get the first 14 items to remain in the original `ItemCollection` and the latter 16 (or however many) moved to a new `ItemCollection`.

How can I do this? `myVar.CopyTo()` would be ok, but there is no parameter for the number of items to copy, and it only accepts an `Array` for output. Looping over `myVar.RemoveAt()` seems expensive. Is there a built-in method? Is it possible with Linq?

Comment: How can you even create ItemCollection instances?

Comment: @helb It originally comes from a `DataGrid`'s `Items`, but is passed down through a couple of methods that handle printing. Each item has multiple data columns.

Comment: I think you are trying to implement something that belongs into a ViewModel / Controller class. Try to split the data in your Model / ViewModel instead of splitting the data which belongs to the UI.

Comment: @helb The data in the `DataGrid` is entered dynamically. E.g. some of the data is loaded from a DB; some is added by the user via the UI. The methods are now complete, with the exception of multi-page printing. The printing class can handle a maximum of 14 rows. All I'm trying to do now is run the `Print` method recursively.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've ended up doing within my `Print` class:

```
var Data = ...; // The original ItemCollection
var DataExcess = new DataGrid().Items; // It isn't possible to use new ItemCollection();

for(var i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++) {
    if(i > 13) {
        DataExcess.Add(Data[i]);
        continue;
    }

    // Otherwise print the row to the page using e.Graphics.DrawString(..)
}

if(DataExcess.Count > 0) {
    new Print(Some, Parameters, Here, ..., DataExcess).Print();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you could convert the `ItemCollection` into an `ArrayList`; then you can try this:

```
arraylist.RemoveRange( x, y );
```

This removes `y` elements starting at index `x`.

Finally you could convert the `ArrayList` back to an `ItemCollection`.

This is useful if you have too many items in the collection.

Comment: I can get the `ItemCollection` into an `ArrayList`, but not back into an `ItemCollection` afterwards. Any ideas? `var DataExcess = new ArrayList(Data); DataExcess.RemoveRange(0, 14);`